# Why are there two sink input index generated by pulseaudio?

Tags: sound, games, pulseaudio, alsa, opengl

I'm planning to spawn a thread as I detect a new sink input index in pulseaudio. But when I run some application, I find out that a second sink index for same client is created.

The system spawns a thread and closes the first thread, which has nothing to do with the current running program. I am tracing this as a reference which is generated by running my code, which detects new sink input index as generated when I run the openarena game.

```
****Sink input Playback Stream with index 0 is detected hello****
=======[ Sink Input# 0 ]=======
Name: Playback Stream
client:11
sink:0
sample format:3
sample rate:44100
sample channels:2
owner module:7
buffer usec:160068
sink usec:210498
Driver:protocol-native.c
client name :Warzone 2100

****Removing sink input 0****

****Sink input Playback Stream with index 1 is detected hello****
=======[ Sink Input# 1 ]=======
Name: Playback Stream
client:11
sink:0
sample format:3
sample rate:44100
sample channels:2
owner module:7
buffer usec:346689
sink usec:23883
Driver:protocol-native.c
client name :Warzone 2100

****Removing sink input 1****

****Sink input Playback Stream with index 2 is detected hello****
=======[ Sink Input# 2 ]=======
Name: Playback Stream
client:13
sink:0
sample format:3
sample rate:44100
sample channels:2
owner module:7
buffer usec:160068
sink usec:210488
Driver:protocol-native.c
client name :torcs-bin

****Removing sink input 2****

****Sink input Playback Stream with index 3 is detected hello****
=======[ Sink Input# 3 ]=======
Name: Playback Stream
client:13
sink:0
sample format:3
sample rate:44100
sample channels:2
owner module:7
buffer usec:347052
sink usec:23997
Driver:protocol-native.c
client name :torcs-bin

****Removing sink input 3****

****Sink input Playback Stream with index 4 is detected hello****
=======[ Sink Input# 4 ]=======
Name: Playback Stream
client:20
sink:0
sample format:3
sample rate:44100
sample channels:2
owner module:7
buffer usec:160068
sink usec:210464
Driver:protocol-native.c
client name :ioquake3

****Removing sink input 4****

****Sink input Playback Stream with index 5 is detected hello****
=======[ Sink Input# 5 ]=======
Name: Playback Stream
client:20
sink:0
sample format:3
sample rate:44100
sample channels:2
owner module:7
buffer usec:346507
sink usec:23980
Driver:protocol-native.c
client name :ioquake3

****Removing sink input 5****
****Sink input Simple DirectMedia Layer with index 6 is detected hello****
=======[ Sink Input# 6 ]=======
Name: Simple DirectMedia Layer
client:24
sink:0
sample format:0
sample rate:11025
sample channels:1
owner module:7
buffer usec:265147
sink usec:105270
Driver:protocol-native.c
client name :Test stream

****Removing sink input 6****

****Sink input Playback Stream with index 7 is detected hello****
=======[ Sink Input# 7 ]=======
Name: Playback Stream
client:26
sink:0
sample format:3
sample rate:44100
sample channels:2
owner module:7
buffer usec:91133
sink usec:209540
Driver:protocol-native.c
client name :MegaGlest

****Removing sink input 7****

****Sink input Playback Stream with index 8 is detected hello****
=======[ Sink Input# 8 ]=======
Name: Playback Stream
client:26
sink:0
sample format:3
sample rate:44100
sample channels:2
owner module:7
buffer usec:347233
sink usec:22750
Driver:protocol-native.c
client name :MegaGlest

****Removing sink input 8****
```

The only difference between this sink index 0 and 1 is the buffer usec and sink 
usec, which is the one I found.

I want to know what the reason behind this is. Why does it create 2 sink input index every time I run this game or any other game (I also tried on other games and I got same result).

Comment: I reworded your question some more, especially adding '.' and ',' where I think should be one. I hope the meaning of everything is still correct and someone with more knowledge than I can help you. Press "edit" on your question and correct it, if something isn't right with my changes.

Comment: This is unusual. Is this the case with all your applications, or is it restricted to games using the quake3 engine?

Comment: @takkat i added some more result with other applications like warzone 2100,torcs, openarena,megaglest

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the applications send multiple streams simultaneously (e.g. music & sound effects). How would this be an issue with your application?

Comment: spawn thread record audio data using monitor source & dump into file but here i am getting 2 files for same application in which first file always have size 0 byte and actual recored data present in second file with no loss  of audio with good quality but it creates unnecessary extra thread for first sink index and i want avoid this first thread on condition but i cant understand on which condition should i differentiate this thread their is no difference between them

Comment: I thought same as @Takkat. Because those tests are with games, my 1st was SDL but Torcs wasn't using it. I flip to libopenal which is common for all those games. Could you try another game not in the list. `apt-cache showpkg libopenal1`